# could we deny permissions to Db User which is a member of db_owner Role in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions, roles, ownership

In some documents, it is said that when you make a database user a member of a DB_owner role, you cannot revoke some permissions from that user, because in fact, by doing so, you will violate the properties of the DB_owner. But I simply made a user a member of this role and then denied the select permission from that user. The result was that the user simply cannot select from the query and view the rows. Why did this problem arise?

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER NewAccount
DENY SELECT ON dbo.TestTable TO NewAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

> it is said that when you make a database user a member of a DB_owner
> role, you cannot revoke some permissions from that user

No that isn't correct as your experiment shows. Presumably the confusion [is from the "Summary of the permission check algorithm"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) which says

> Bypass the permission check if the login is a member of the sysadmin
> fixed server role or if the user is the dbo user in the current
> database.

But "[dbo user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-using-user_name-without-an-id)" and "member of DB_owner role" are [not equivalent](https://serverfault.com/a/247119/39535).